# Difference in performance for Coin Change between Haskell and C++

Tags: performance, haskell, comparison

I was trying to implement the Coin Change problem in Haskell. The problem is as follows:

> Given a set of coins and an infinite supply of those coins, find the minimum number of coins that it will require to make a certain value, say n.

I wrote the following program in haskell:

```
import Data.Vector ((!), generate)
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

coins = [1, 5, 10, 25, 100] :: [Int]

coinchangev :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
coinchangev n cs = v ! n
 where v = generate (n+1) f
       f 0 = 0
       f n = 1 + minimum [v ! x | x <- map (n-) cs, x >= 0]

main :: IO ()
main = do n <- read <$> getLine :: IO Int
           putStrLn . show $ coinchangev n coins
```

I wrote the following program in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef vector<int> row;

const row coins {1, 5, 10, 25, 100};
#define INT_MAX 9999999;

int coinchange(const int n, const row& coins) {
    row v(n+1, 0);

    for (int i=1; i<n+1; i++) {
        int min = INT_MAX;

        for (int j=0; j<coins.size(); j++) {
            int x = i - coins[j];
            if (x >= 0 && v[x] < min) {
                min = v[x];
            }
        }

        v[i] = 1 + min;
    }

    return v.back();
}

int main() {
    int n; cin >> n;
    cout << coinchange(n, coins) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the haskell version with `ghc -O3` (version 7.8.4) and the c++ version with `g++ --std=c++1y -O3` (version 4.8.4).

For the input `10000000` my haskell program takes much longer than my c++ version to complete. Here are the timings that were measured using time:

Haskell: `6.40user 0.85system 0:07.26elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2664316maxresident)k 
152inputs+0outputs (1major+647822minor)pagefaults 0swaps`

C++: `0.08user 0.00system 0:00.08elapsed 97%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 39964maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+936minor)pagefaults 0swaps`

My question is why I'm seeing such a large difference and what steps I can take (if any) to improve the performance of the Haskell code. I had expected performance to be basically equivalent (at least within the same order). My objective was to keep the solution simple (and hopefully idiomatic) in both languages.

Comment: For what its worth, Im not too sure about my use of vectors, maybe thats the problem?

Comment: If you add `+RTS -s` when you call your executable, you'll note that GC takes most of the time.

Comment: Why do people continuously believe `-O3` is a GHC option? GHC's optimization levels max out at 2.

Comment: @Zeta I appreciate the feedback, but I don't know how to use that information to make this faster. Maybe you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Carl `-O2` did not make any difference in the numbers.

Comment: Using `[x | x <- map ((v!) . (n-)) cs, x >= 0]` instead of `[v ! x | x <- map (n-) cs, x >= 0]` brought execution time down to `2.18user 0.29system 0:02.48elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 983660maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+226603minor)pagefaults 0swaps`

Comment: What does profiling tell you?

Comment: @jberryman mostly the same things as the time output -- reduced time and memory usage. I am a little new to the `+RTS -s` option so my profiling may not be the greatest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unboxed vectors might help here:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U ((!), constructN, length)

coinchangev :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
coinchangev n cs = v ! n
 where v = constructN (n+1) f
       f w = case U.length w of
             0 -> 0
             m -> 1 + minimum [w ! x | x <- map (m-) cs, x >= 0]
```

Original code:

```
$ time ./CoinChange 
100000

real    0m12.543s
user    0m11.742s
sys 0m0.800s
```

Unboxed variant:

```
$ time ./CoinChange2
100000

real    0m1.598s
user    0m1.588s
sys 0m0.012s
```

Original C++:

```
$ time ./CoinChange_cpp 
100000

real    0m0.084s
user    0m0.072s
sys 0m0.012s
```

Comment: Lol, I just tried this myself and I'm amazed at the difference. The last time measurements `0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3856maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+568minor)pagefaults 0swaps` -- Beating even my C++ implementation (although this is one off and in terms of statistics, insignificant)

Comment: What is surprising though is why in the boxed case, manual fusion produced so much difference -- I would've expected ghc to automatically fuse those loops.

Answer (score 0):

I found that taking the length of the actual computed change is quite fast. (The coin list has to be sorted in descending order)

```
module Main where

change :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
change 0 _ = []
change _ [] = []
change amount coins@(c:cs)
   | c <= amount = c : change (amount - c) coins
   | otherwise  = change amount cs

main :: IO ()
main =
  print $ length $ change 10000000 [100, 25, 10, 5, 1]
```

Comment: Hi, this solution is fast because it does not do the same thing as my implementation -- it just finds one way of producing n, not the one with the smallest number of coins. Consider `n=15` and `coins = [12, 10, 5, 1]`. This gives 4 whereas the correct answer is 2.

Comment: OK got it! I haven't seen this case first! Now the problem is more interesting to me :)